# App send texts that cost money

Tags: applications, sms

I accidentally allowed Text permissions on an app and in the same second I was hit with three texts in my spam folder.

I went to texts and there I saw that my phone sent some code and than sent yes to some number and it said that it will cost me weekly.

What should I do?

Comment: Remove the permission! If it's an app that you don't need, uninstall it.

Comment: I deleted it, but ut subscribed and i deleted sms number. Is there any way of finding that number

Comment: Dispute the next "weekly charge" with your bank or credit card company